# Tangent space change of bases

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $M\subset \Bbb{R}^m$ be a $k$-dimensional differentiable submanifold. Let $(\varphi, U)$ and $(\psi, V)$ be two charts for $p\in M$ with $\varphi(x)=p$ and $\psi(y)=p$. Then we have two bases for the tangent space $T_p M$, namely $\{ (p, \partial_i \varphi(x)) : i=1,...,k \}$ and $\{ (p, \partial_i \psi(y)) : i=1,...,k \}$.

I would like to find a **change of bases** from the basis given by $\psi$ to the basis given by $\varphi$.

So we want to express a tangent vector $(p, \partial_i \psi(y))$ as a linear combination of basis elements $(p, \partial_j \varphi(y))$. I'm lacking good ideas for how to approach this, so I'm thankful for any help.

Comment: "Apply the chain rule." :) (Incidentally, one of your $\psi$'s in your final paragraph (the first?) should probably be $\varphi$...?)

Comment: I corrected the mistake. Can you please elaborate on how I can apply the chain rule?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Here's the situation for dimension two. The generalization to arbitrary dimension is straightforward.

In classical notation, if $(y_{1}, y_{2})$ are smooth functions of $(x_{1}, x_{2})$, the chain rule reads
\begin{align*}
\frac{\dd}{\dd x_{1}}
  &= \frac{\dd y_{1}}{\dd x_{1}}\, \frac{\dd}{\dd y_{1}}
   + \frac{\dd y_{2}}{\dd x_{1}}\, \frac{\dd}{\dd y_{2}}, \\
\frac{\dd}{\dd x_{2}}
  &= \frac{\dd y_{1}}{\dd x_{2}}\, \frac{\dd}{\dd y_{1}}
   + \frac{\dd y_{2}}{\dd x_{2}}\, \frac{\dd}{\dd y_{2}}.
\end{align*}
In modern guise, if $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism and $y = \phi(x)$, the preceding system expresses the push-forwards $\phi_{*}(\dd x_{i})$ as linear combinations of the $\dd y_{j}$, namely
\begin{align*}
\phi_{*}\frac{\dd}{\dd x_{1}}
  &= \frac{\dd \phi_{1}}{\dd x_{1}}\, \frac{\dd}{\dd y_{1}}
   + \frac{\dd \phi_{2}}{\dd x_{1}}\, \frac{\dd}{\dd y_{2}}, \\
\phi_{*}\frac{\dd}{\dd x_{2}}
  &= \frac{\dd \phi_{1}}{\dd x_{2}}\, \frac{\dd}{\dd y_{1}}
   + \frac{\dd \phi_{2}}{\dd x_{2}}\, \frac{\dd}{\dd y_{2}}.
\end{align*}
Note that the change of basis matrix is just the Jacobian of $\phi$. (If you need to get expressions "in the other direction", push the $\dd y_{j}$ forward by the diffeomorphism $\phi^{-1}$.)

---

**Added**: Let $n$, $p$, and $m$ be positive integers, $x = (x_{1}, \dots, x_{n})$ coordinates on $\Reals^{n}$, $y = (y_{1}, \dots, y_{p})$ coordinates on $\Reals^{p}$, and $z = (z_{1}, \dots, z_{m})$ coordinates on $\Reals^{m}$. If $g:\Reals^{n} \to \Reals^{p}$ and $f:\Reals^{p} \to \Reals^{m}$ are smooth mappings, $Dg(x)$ is the $p \times n$ matrix of partial derivatives of $g$ at $x$, and $Df(y)$ is the $m \times p$ matrix of partials of $f$ at $y = g(x)$, the chain rule asserts that
$$
D(f \circ g)(x) = Df\bigl(g(x)\bigr) Dg(x).
$$
Classically, if $y = g(x)$ and $z = f(y)$, the preceding matrix product takes the form
$$
\frac{\dd z_{i}}{\dd x_{j}}
  = \sum_{k=1}^{p} \frac{\dd z_{i}}{\dd y_{k}}\, \frac{\dd y_{k}}{\dd x_{j}}.
\tag{1}
$$
(The standard caveat is: On the left, "$z = (f \circ g)(x)$ is a function of $x$", while on the right, "$z = f(y)$ is a function of $y$".)

As you say, "a tangent vector is a directional derivative"; that means a *differential operator*, not a partial derivative of a particular mapping. In a chart with coordinates $x$, the *coordinate vector fields* are the differential operators
$$
\frac{\dd}{\dd x_{1}}, \dots, \frac{\dd}{\dd x_{n}}
$$
associated to the standard basis fields in $\Reals^{n}$. (Incidentally, this means the notation "$(p, \dd_{i}\psi(y))$" is anomalous, because you're not taking partial derivatives of $\psi$. Presumably it means "$V$ is a neighborhood of $p$, $\psi:V \to \Reals^{k}$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image, $y = (y_{1}, \dots, y_{k})$ are the associated local coordinates in $V$, i.e., $y$ is the expression of $\psi$ in local coordinates, and the $\dd_{i} = \dd/\dd y_{i}$ are coordinate vector fields.")

Equation (1) holds for arbitrary smooth functions $z_{i}$, so we may (by "erasing the $z$'s") interpret (1) as *a relationship between tangent vector fields*. The resulting equation (with $n = p = m = 2$) is the system in my original post.

In your situation, $y = \psi \circ \varphi^{-1}(x)$.

I hope that clarifies while still leaving an educational amount of computation and pondering to you. If the business of differential operators is baffling, do you have an instructor you can consult?

Comment: Is $\frac{ \partial }{ \partial x_1 } = \partial_1 \varphi$ ? And what is $\frac{\dd y_{1}}{\dd x_{1}}$ ? How is this the chain rule?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your notation; I read "$\dd_{i}\varphi(x)$" as the $i$th coordinate vector field in the coordinate system $x$ defined by $\varphi$", which (as you've guessed) is often denoted $\dd/\dd x_{i}$. To clarify, how do you view tangent vectors, and how do you think of the chain rule in multivariable calculus?

Comment: By $\partial_i \varphi$ I mean the vector consisting of the i-th partial derivatives of the components of $\varphi$. I view tangent vectors in some point $p$ as directional derivative of some chart at the point $p$. I only know the chain rule as $(f(g(x)))' = f'(g(x)) g'(x)$. Thank you.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, so, the answer is 
$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_{i}} = \sum \frac{\partial }{\partial \psi_{k}} \frac{\partial \psi_{k}}{\partial \phi_{i}} $ ? How does it simplify?

Comment: @pipita: Pretty much "yes", though it's probably more customary to write $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}} = \sum_{k} \frac{\partial y_{k}}{\partial x_{i}}\, \frac{\partial}{\partial y_{k}}$. Not sure what you mean by "How does it simplify?" The coordinate vector fields in one chart generally look complicated in another chart.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, what i mean is:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1695767/change-of-coordinates-between-charts

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang i dont know why but i cant mention your name with the at in the other post .

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, how do you conclude (2) in the other post? i doesnt make sense for me