# Change of coordinates between charts

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold, $(U, \phi)$ and $(V,\psi)$ two coordinate charts and $p$ a point of $M$. Let $\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_{1}} (p), \ldots, \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_{n}} (p) \}$ and $\{ \frac{\partial}{\partial \psi_{1}}(p), \ldots, \frac{\partial}{\partial \psi_{n}}(p) \}$ two basis of $T_{p} M$
I want to find the change of basis matrix between the two charts.

My try: 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi_{i}} (p) =  \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\partial}{\partial (\psi \circ \phi^{-1})_{k}} \frac{\partial (\psi \circ \phi^{-1})_{k}}{\partial \phi_{i}} (p)$$

Well i think is this, but now how do i put this into a matrix?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Basis}{\mathbf{e}}\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space with bases $B = (\Basis_{j})_{j=1}^{n}$ and $B' = (\Basis_{i}')_{i=1}^{n}$. If
$$
\Basis_{j} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} A_{ij} \Basis_{i}'\quad\text{for all $j$,}
$$
the change of basis matrix from $B$ to $B'$ is $A = [A_{ij}]$.

In your situation, assume $\phi$ and $\psi$ map $p$ to the origin, and let $(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n})$ and $(y_{1}, \dots, y_{n})$ denote the respective coordinate representations, so that $(y_{1}, \dots, y_{n}) = \psi \circ \phi^{-1}(x_{1}, \dots, x_{n})$.

In classical notation you get the change of basis matrix for bases of $\Reals^{n} = T_{0} \Reals^{n}$:
$$
\Basis_{j} = \frac{\dd}{\dd x_{j}},\quad
%
\Basis_{i}' = \frac{\dd}{\dd y_{i}},\quad
%
A_{ij} = \frac{\dd y_{i}}{\dd x_{j}};
$$
the chain rule reads
$$
\frac{\dd}{\dd x_{j}}
  = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\dd y_{i}}{\dd x_{j}}\, \frac{\dd}{\dd y_{i}}.
\tag{1}
$$

To express this as a change of basis in $T_{p}M$, write the images of the standard basis as
$$
\frac{\dd}{\dd \phi}
  = (\phi^{-1})_{*} \frac{\dd}{\dd x},\qquad
\frac{\dd}{\dd \psi}
  = (\psi^{-1})_{*} \frac{\dd}{\dd x},
$$
and express the chain rule as
$$
\frac{\dd}{\dd \phi}
  = (\phi^{-1} \circ \psi)_{*}\; (\psi^{-1})_{*}\frac{\dd}{\dd x}
  = (\phi^{-1} \circ \psi)_{*} \frac{\dd}{\dd \psi}.
$$
In terms of individual basis elements,
$$
\frac{\dd}{\dd \phi_{j}}
  = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\dd (\phi^{-1} \circ \psi)_{i}}{\dd \phi_{j}}\, \frac{\dd}{\dd \psi_{i}}.
\tag{2}
$$
(The last is not quite what you have; it's possible I've misconstrued your notation. The important thing is, of course, to express elements of one basis of $T_{p}M$ as linear combinations of elements of another basis.)

Comment: but my $e'_{i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \psi_{i}}$ otherwise i would not have a change of basis matrix

Comment: are you sure about e' ?

Comment: You're right that my second expression for $\Basis_{i}'$ is awry; perhaps the moral is not to use partial derivative symbols except with local coordinates. :) Will fix this shortly.

Comment: how do you get (2) ? and is it in function of $x_{0}$ ?

Comment: (2) is read directly off the preceding line (which is a matrix equation), but is predicated on my (possibly incorrect) understanding of the notation $\dd/\dd\phi_{j}$, etc.

Comment: Could you please explain better how did you get that? I still dont understand (and sorry about de @.. i thought it was always necessary)

Comment: In terms of the "[push-forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_%28differential%29)" of a vector field by a smooth map, the idea is to write $\phi^{-1} = (\phi^{-1} \circ \psi) \circ \psi^{-1}$, then to use each side to push forward the standard basis $\dd/\dd x$.