# Covering smooth dynamical systems with charts

Tags: geometry, dynamical-systems

I have been studying differential geometry and dynamical systems. I learned, that in smooth geometry, there are all those objects, operations, and morphisms: metric, pushforward, pullback, tangent space, (co)-vectors, Lie brackets. For dynamical systems, we also have a plural vocabulary: flow, eigenvectors, and holonomicity. My question is:

Given a dynamical system $\Sigma$ given by tuple $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{X})$ and defined by position vector $x^i \partial_i$ respective to origin point $\mathcal{O}$ such that velocity vector $\dot{x} \in T_\mathcal{O} \mathcal{X}$ is given by smooth map $a(x)$. For a countable covering atlas $(\varphi_i, U_i)$, how can we describe $a(x)$ in local coordinate chat $U_i$ i.e. local coordinates $\{u_i^j\}$?

I hope this is not too complicated. I am new to this, and everything is so "competitive", it is hard to learn it by myself.

Comment: $x^i \partial_i$ is not a position vector on a manifold... It's a velocity vector. If you have your flow expressed in one coordinate chart already (otherwise how exactly are you defining the flow in your post?) you just use the transition maps to change charts.

Comment: I mean: as far as I understand, charts $U_i$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{\mbox{card}(U_i)}$. And $x^i \partial_i$ has no dot over it, why can't we call it "position vector"? I mean, if we all define based on LOCAL coordinate vector field, isn't it TOO dynamic and locally dependent?

Comment: You should read a proper textbook on differential topology. I learned from Lee's book on Smooth Manifolds and find it a decent reference. Your questions imply to me you have not properly read nor internalized the definitions. In any case, you mean dimension rather than cardinality (and the dimension is usually assumed to be constant, at least on connected components but usually between components as well) and a dot above is physics notation that represents a flow (usually in tangent bundle). $\partial_i$ are a basis for the tangent space $T_p M$ (thinking of velocity vectors as derivations).

Comment: I agree with you, I have the book on my shelf. Let me picture something: take your desk as a solid object whose some dynamic system flows through as volume; out of the blue, there is a leaf that touches, not with a beak, and the dynamical system is also defined on it. It means: the contact between tangent spaces (I heard about jets, maybe it is something another), allows us to describe objects with tangent spaces with different dimension (Thanks, card is used at set theory xD).  But as I said, I wish to define something like $\dot{u}$ instead of $\dot{x}$.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I mean, I can do the push forwad $\dot{x} = f_* \dot{u}$ for some vector $\dot{u}$ belonging to tangent space $T_u U_i$ such that $x = \varphi(u)$, and build the inverse map $\varphi^{-1}_i(u)$ such that $f_* \dot{u} = (a \circ \varphi^{-1}_i) (u)$. But how can I perform the inverse of pushforward $f_*^{-1}$? In $\mathbb{R}^n$ space, it would be the regular Jacobian inverse $J^{-1}_{\varphi_i}$, right!?

Comment: What you're describing involves structures other than pure differential topology. You'd have to model the leaf (likely as some triangulation held together by internal forces) and then numerically solve a PDE describing flow along the surface, and then describe how the leaf interacts with the flow (presumably you'd need to model friction to have it be dragged along?). In any case, it's a physics/analysis/differential geometry problem. As far as your question on expressing the function $a(x)$ in charts: you have to give me a definition of how you're defining $a(x)$.

Comment: If your $f$ is invertible (which it need not be) then the pushforward $f_*$ (which is the Jacobian in coordinates) has an inverse $(f_*)^{-1} = (f^{-1})_*$ (which is the inverse of the Jacobian in coordinates). What you wrote is correct.

Comment: I inclined to think, vectors are locally defined, but I prefer to define them respective to an origin point $\mathcal{O}$. It means, given coordinate vector field $\{X_i\}$ on origin point $\mathcal{O}$, we define both velocity vector $\dot{x}$ and smooth vector map $a(x)$ all respective to these vectors along i.e. $a^i X_i$, or $a^i \partial_i$, in Einstein's notation, as we like.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen this means, the answer is $\dot{u} = \overbrace{(\varphi_i^{-1})_* \, (a \circ \varphi_i^{-1})}^{\alpha}(u)$. Thanks, bro. :)

Comment: No problem. The fact the Jacobian of the inverse is the same as the inverse of the Jacobian is called the "Inverse Function Theorem", and the equivalent statement for pushforwards I mentioned above holds by just working in coordinates. Regarding changing coordinates for $a(x)$, you first express it in one coordinate system (as something of the form $x^i \partial_i$) and then change coordinates between charts using the chain rule, e.g. see here:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1695767/269764.

Comment: We managed to do rocket science on SO comments. We rock! :)

Comment: Once you learn some differential geometry, you often end up working with functions defined in terms of other functions, e.g. $a(x)$ could depend not only on the point (in the tangent bundle) $x^i \partial_i$, but also on functions defined using the coordinates (often a metric tensor, which allows us to talk about geometrical stuff like curvature and differential equations which allow us to do things like physics). For example, see the definition of a Laplacian on a manifold here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen my simple engineering example is: I have a small robot with preferential directions to move: In a flat plane, there are no restrictions; In steep plane, We must consider already the immersed space; In a curved space, the once flat model is still the same, but we have to use some chart $(u, \phi(u))$ to describe the floor topology...

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen $\mathbin\bigtriangleup f(x) = \mbox{div}_{\mathcal{X}}(\mbox{grad}_{\mathcal{X} }f)$ is very much to me. :O

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I have been wondering how those video-game simulators make their cars drive so smoothly through the landscape. The only way I can think of, is by world modeling and differential equations.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Would you take a look at post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458042/covariant-derivative-nabla-dot-gamma-dot-gamma-of-constrained-velocit?_gl=1*81x5t3*_ga*NjY4NjE2MzExLjE2OTY1MTM4Mzc.*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY5OTU1OTc2Ni4zMy4xLjE2OTk1NTk5OTIuMC4wLjA. ?